# SQL DML Query AVG and COUNT

Tags: sql

I am beginner at SQL and I am trying to create a query.

I have these tables:

```
CREATE TABLE Hospital (
    hid INT PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(127) UNIQUE,
    country VARCHAR(127),
    area INT
);
CREATE TABLE Doctor (
    ic INT PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(127),
    date_of_birth INT,
);
CREATE TABLE Work (
    hid INT,
    ic INT,
    since INT,
    FOREIGN KEY (hid) REFERENCES Hospital (hid),
    FOREIGN KEY (ic) REFERENCES Doctor (ic),
    PRIMARY KEY (hid,ic)
 );
```

The query is: What is the average in each country of the number of doctors working in hospitals of that country (1st column: each country, 2nd column: average)? Thanks.

Comment: how will you calculate the average in your case? can you provide example?

Comment: Do you want the average across all countries? Do you want ONE number result that represents the average number of doctors in each country?

Comment: I 1st will count the number of doctors that work on Hospital1 (for example 2) in England plus the doctors on the Hospital2 in England (for example 4) and then I have to do the average wich is 3. In the result I will have in the first column: England and second column: 3.

Comment: Do you want "the average number of doctors per hospital" by country?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You first need to write a query that counts the doctors per hospital

```
select w.hid, count(w.ic)
from work w
group by w.hid;
```

Based on that query, you can retrieve the average number of doctors per country:

```
with doctor_count as (
  select w.hid, count(w.ic) as cnt
  from work w
  group by w.hid
)
select h.country, avg(dc.cnt)
from hospital h
  join doctor_count dc on h.hid = dc.hid
group by h.country;
```

If you have an old DBMS that does not support common table expressions the above can be rewritten as:

```
select h.country, avg(dc.cnt)
from hospital h
  join (
    select w.hid, count(w.ic) as cnt
    from work 
    group by w.hid
  ) dc on h.hid = dc.hid;
```

Here is an SQLFiddle demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/9ff79/1

Btw: storing `date_of_birth` as an integer is a bad choice. You should use a real `DATE` column.

And `work` is a reserved word in SQL. You shouldn't use that for a table name.